# Can I have one picture for all sizes in a product with Woocommerce?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I have a hoodie product that comes in 30 different colours. It has 6 different sizes. This creates 180 "products" that I have to click on and set an image for.

This seems massively overcomplicated. I'd like to be able to set an image for each colour variation, but not for each colour/size variation, as the image will be the same regardless of whether it's small, medium, large, whatever.

Is there any way I can do this or am I stuck with having to create 180 different variations of the hoodie in which I have to set the same image for each 6 sizes per colour variation?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is "Yes"!  I just discovered that there is a "Any size" option where I set the colour and that's it for all sizes. Phew!

Comment: Maybe I spoke too soon. The second product I did this with, it didn't work!